# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError in flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been reading the SQLAlchemy docs, but I don't understand them. The error (UnmappedInstanceError) says something isn't mapped. What isn't mapped? I really don't get sqlalchemy and I want to go back to using naked sqlite, but so many people recommend this, so I thought I should learn it.  Here is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj2\app\views.py", line 170, in add_manentry
db.session.add(q)

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 149, in do
return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1452, in add
raise exc.UnmappedInstanceError(instance)

UnmappedInstanceError: Class '__builtin__.unicode' is not mapped
```

Here is the applicable code:

```
@app.route('/addm', methods=['POST'])
def add_mentry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    form = MForm(request.form)
    filename = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cover = request.files['cover']
        if cover and allowed_file(cover.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(cover.filename)
            cover = cover.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

    q = request.form['name']
    # do for 12 more fields
    db.session.add(q)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('moutput'))
```

Comment: you're not alone not understanding sql alchemy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
q = request.form['name']
# do for 12 more fields
db.session.add(q)
```

`request.form['name']` will return a unicode value. Then, you do...

```
db.session.add(q)
```

The goal of the session is to keep track of Entities (Python objects), not individual unicode values as you seem to be trying to do it (See [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html) for more on what the session does). Thus, you should be adding objects that have a mapping (such as a `User` object as shown in the ["Mapping" section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping) of the [ORM tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html)), but you're actually passing a simple unicode value

What you're using is just one part of SQLAlchemy: the ORM (Object-Relational Mapper). The ORM will try to do things like allow you to create a new python object and have the SQL automatically generaeted by "adding" the object to the session..

```
a = MyEntity()
session.add(a)
session.commit() # Generates SQL to do an insert for the table that MyEntity is for
```

Keep in mind that you can use SQLAlchemy without using the ORM functionality. You could just do `db.execute('INSERT...', val1, val2)` to replace your already "naked" SQL. SQLAlchemy will provide you connection pooling, etc (although if you're using SQLite, you probably don't care about connection pooling).

If you want to understand Flask-SQLAlchemy, I would first recommend understanding how SQLAlchemy works (especially the ORM side) by trying it out using simple scripts (as shown in the [tutorials](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html). Then you'll understand how Flask-SQLAlchemy would work with it.

Comment: I see. I'm very new to python in general (I'm making this program in order to learn since I learn better by doing), but there are still a lot of terms I don't get. Like object. This is what I tried to do: `name = form.name.data \n q = MForm(name, obj=name)`. It gives me the error `TypeError: formdata should be a multidict-type wrapper that supports the 'getlist' method`, which is the error I get when I follow the tutorials. The tutorials I've read that use flask-sqlalchemy use the ORM functions, so I didn't want to exclude them. I'll keep reading the docs because I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: See if you can start smaller and build up. Don't worry about SQLAlchemy for now, and concentrate on Flask and the form library (or forget Flask and forms and concentrate on SQLAlchemy). That way you're less likely to have an error in one make you think you are failing an understanding in the other.

Comment: Ok. I had already finished it with just SQLite, so I thought I could go fancier and save myself some future headaches. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 17):

When you are adding a non-model-object into the session, you will be getting `UnmappedInstanceError`.

In your case, `q` was probably an unicode string, not a model object. (It appears that you are using Python 2.x because in Python 3.x, it will say str), this was the line of the root cause for `UnmappedInstanceError: Class '__builtin__.unicode' is not mapped`:

```
  File "C:\Users\Me\repos\mandj2\app\views.py", line 170, in add_manentry
  db.session.add(q)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are changing database see:
You have to address to what item in the object you want to change. See below:

```
client = session.query(Clients).filter_by(id=client_id).one()
if request.method == 'POST':
    new_name = request.form['form_name']
    client.name = new_name
    session.add(client)
    session.commit()
```

As you can see in the 'client' object, we have "name" among other info inside the object. We want to directly change 'name' only, therefore you need to address to it. (client.name)

---

If you are adding new thing to database:
Here when you add a new value to the database with orm, you need to specify the item in the object that is receiving the data.
in this case (Client.name)

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_name = request.form['form_name']
        name = Clients(name=new_name)
        session.add(name)
        session.commit()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a problem like this. In the following code below, I tried to delete some posts:

```
@app.route('/categorydeletion', methods=['POST'])
def deletecategory():
    name_of_category = request.form['categoryname']
    category_to_be_deleted = Category.query.filter_by(name=name_of_category).first()
    accompained_post = Posts.query.filter_by(category_id=category_to_be_deleted.id).all()
    if category:`enter code here`
        db.session.delete(category_to_be_deleted)
        db.session.delete(accomapained_post)
        db.session.commit()
        return 'successful
```

But I was getting the same error `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError`

So my fix was this below:

```
@app.route('/categorydeletion', methods=['POST'])
def deletecategory():
    name_of_category = request.form['categoryname']
    category_to_be_deleted = Category.query.filter_by(name=name_of_category).first()
    accompained_post = Posts.query.filter_by(category_id=category_to_be_deleted.id).all()
    if category:
        db.session.delete(category_to_be_deleted)

        def delete_accomapained_post():
            for i in accompained_post:
                db.session.delete(i)

        delete_accomapained_post()
        db.session.commit()
        return 'successful'
```

As @devy pointed out, you work with python objects; with the first scenario I was working with a python list.

But in the second scenario, I had to create a function `delete_accomapained_post()` to loop through the list to access the Python objects that I want to work with.