# Could not Submit data from form to SQLAlchemy: sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I followed the tutorial to learned Python sqlAlchemy from this tutorial [Building a CRUD application with Flask and SQLAlchemy](https://www.codementor.io/garethdwyer/building-a-crud-application-with-flask-and-sqlalchemy-dm3wv7yu2) for the beginning level, and everything was going fine.

Until then, I went one step further to create another model `publisher` 
 just as the same as the book model which the whole script is as following:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
database_file = "sqlite:///{}".format(os.path.join(project_dir,"bookdatabase.db"))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_file

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Book(db.Model):
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        super(Book,self).__init__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Title: {}".format(self.title)

class Publisher(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        super(Publisher,self).__init__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Name: {}".format(self.name)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def home():
    if request.form:
        book = Book(title=request.form.get('title'))
        db.session.add(book)
        db.session.commit()

        pub = Publisher(name=request.form.get('pub_name'))
        db.session.add(Publisher)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**home.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
    <fieldset>
        <p>Book Title: <input type="text" name="title"></p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <p>Pub Name: <input type="text" name="pub_name"></p>
    </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

After form was submitted, I got the error :

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError
>   UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'flask_sqlalchemy._BoundDeclarativeMeta' is not mapped; was a class (**main**.Publisher) supplied where an instance was required?

Knowing there is some user met this similar problem such as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196824/sqlalchemy-orm-exc-unmappedinstanceerror-in-flask?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but I still could not get the point to solve this problem.

Please kindly help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Try: db.session.add(pub) instead. As the error says, you should pass the instance not the class itself.

Comment: Carefully reading the error message would help: "was a class (main.Publisher) supplied where an instance was required?"

Comment: @ziiiro, it working as expected, thanks